# Which way Visual Studio 2022 compiles size_t without any include files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Which way this:

```
int main()
{
    size_t a=0;
}
```

compiles with [Visual Studio C++ 2022 (latest version)](https://godbolt.org/z/jK8cEG37z) while it doesn't compile with [CLang](https://godbolt.org/z/Wo1T3z1oq) while **no headers included at all**?

Of course, CLang is correct here. The question is not "Why?", the question is "In which way?".

Intellisense shows `typedef unsigned long long size_t`, but both *Go To Definition* and *Go To Declaration* lead to error messages.

So, the question is, where is it defined and how comes to my source code?

(*Precompiled headers turned off*)

Comment: msvc is as "correct" as clang is. I mean one can expect to get an error, but why would it be guaranteed to get one?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, try any other word (not from build-in types) instead of `size_t` here and get `undeclared identifier` error with any compiler (including MSVC) because compiler doesn't know this type. Why with `size_t` it behaves differently? What is so specific to `size_t` here? How MSVC knows `size_t` here as `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Microsoft's `CL.EXE` has `size_t` predefined **in the compiler**.

Comment: @Eljay, thank you. But why? Should we consider this as a defect or this is a kind of freedom to interpret the standard?

Comment: I do not believe the standard disallows this kind of compiler baked-in predefine.  I don't know how to get a list of what all the compiler predefines.  Does it also have `std::size_t` predefined, or is is just the global namespace `size_t`?  The global namespace is a bit like the wild wild west; no holds barred.

Comment: The standard defines what will be available if you include a header, it doesn't require anything to not be available without the associated includes.

Comment: I think I understand your question, I just don't think your conclusion that msvc is not correct is sound. That doesn't affect the actual question of "how?" or "why is msvc different?"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, if type is not defined, it mustn't compile. No type `size_t` is defined in standard except system headers. Doesn't compilation of this code violate standard? If not, why?

Comment: those are two different questions "Should this be an error?", your premise is that the answer is yes. I think no, but it doesnt change the quesiton you did ask "what does msvc do to make this work?".

Comment: The full type by the way is `std::size_t` (don't use `using namespace std;`. And you need to include at least one of the header files mentioned here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t. Do you include any other header files? Because one of those headers mentioned in cppreference often gets "pulled in" when you include other header files.

Comment: btw I think the distinction is important, because one is a language lawyer question (perhaps a rather simple one), while the other is a question about implementation details of one specific implementation. Framing is very different

Comment: @PepijnKramer, can you please read my question carefully and see the links to the demos? I explicitly stated that **no** files are included at all and demos show this.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, well, let's "divide et impera" and start with the simplest. Am I got you correctly that you consider this code correct and it must compile without any error? If so, I will create a separate question on this for language lawyers.

Comment: you mistunderstand. "you consider this code correct and it must compile without any error" is not what I said, and it is not the opposite of "this code is wrong and a compiler must issue an error"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, so, would the wording "Should compiler report an error for this code?" reflect your point? Are you saying that this particular case could go under umbrella of the cases when the code is ill-formed, but compiler is not obliged to report an error? Or you state that the code is well-formed? Just to be on the same page, do you consider this code ill-formed or not? Should ill-formed code compile?

Comment: @Damir Only the C++ standard defines what's legal and valid. Referring to "size_t" without #including one of the 7 headers that officially declares it is a violation of the standard, period. MSFT's implementation is just an oddity, likely just an historical convenience because "sizeof" (which requires no header) returns a "std::size_t" (interestingly you can assign this to an "auto" without #including any header), but also (I suspect), because many developers relied on <iostream> in the early life of C++ (on VS), which indirectly #included "std::size_t", so MSFT likely just made it implicit.

Comment: @Damir Note BTW that even MSFT's /permissive- option doesn't flag it

Comment: "Should compiler report an error for this code?"  no. THis does not reflect what I am saying. "should" is not binding, its not a guarantee. You didnt spell it out explicitly, but it seems to be a premise of your quesiton that msvc is incorrect, because according to standard it *must* issue an error message for this code. I think its fair to expect an error message, but I dont think that it *must* produce one. I am not aware of such guarantee. And again, I dont think this is essential to the question you are asking here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I can't say if it is essential, since I still can't grasp your wording of the question. For me "Should compiler report an error for this code?" and "I dont think that it must produce one" are absolutely the same, meaning first is the question and the second is your answer to it. I am still interested what is your point, so I would be thankful if you shape your question and the answer you expect to hear from language lawyers so that I could raise the question. Feel free to create yourself, if you wish.

Comment: @Larry, thank you, that's what I expected to hear. The question now in discussion with user *463035818_is_not_an_ai* is, must the compiler issue an error message or not (if I got his concern correctly). As for me, it must and this should be stated somewhere is standard, but I can't find the precise wording so far. Like "otherwise is lexem is not ... the compiler must issue a diagnostic".

Comment: maybe we are actually talking about the same, but I got confused by your use of terms (which in specifications have specific meaning, when a specs says "should" then an implementation that does not can be conforming see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185871/255304 and the link in that answer)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, well, let's put this away for the moment as wording issue since my original question didn't consider any of these terms, first time I used term "should" was in comments and it was the weak requirement and then you first used the word "should" in the program context, so I am lost. Maybe my first use of should in comment "Should we consider this as a defect..." is confusing, but I considered this as a weak requirement. Anyway, I am not a native speaker, so I could feel words in a wrong way. Sorry, if I did.

Comment: @Damir I can't give you a definitive answer and I have decades of C++ experience. It's unlikely you'll get it here (I wouldn't trust anyone anyway), unless an informed committee member weighs in and even then I wouldn't be surprised if there were disagreements (with other members). The standard itself has various passages that generally address the situation. In the C++20 standard for instance, see section 3.57, 3.58, and 4.1.1[1] and 4.1.1[2] (and who knows what other passages may exist). While I have my opinion on what likely applies in this case, I can't confirm it so won't attempt to.

Comment: Hi,@Danur, Is there any update to this question?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT, I am Damir, not Danur, but anyway, what kind of update do you expect? MSVC, trying to do better, paves the way to hell when it comes to write portable code. The `size_t` is no way to use since you are in danger to lost the necessary include files which will lead to issues on standard-compliant compilers. So, the only safe way is to go with `std::size_t` for C++ projects.

Comment: So glad you found your way. I converted your comment into an answer. If it is helpful to you, you could mark it so that it can help more people.

Comment: @user12002570 Out of the 5 dupe links, only the third one is relevant. The rest is about transitive includes, while OP has none. I've removed the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The question incorrectly assumes that `size_t` has to be defined *somewhere* in Visual C++. This is wrong. Some type names are built-in, and for Visual C++ that includes `size_t`

This is incorrect, because according to the standard the following code has to be legal:

```
int main() {
  int size_t = 0;
  return size_t;
}
```

The names of built-in types are reserved, and this code would have been illegal if it had used `float` instead of `size_t`. But since no header is included, `size_t` is not defined as a type, leaving the name available for the variable definition.

Comment: Thank you for the input. You lost me, let me start one by one:(1)Wording is hard, but I can't feel the difference between "where is it defined and how comes to my source code" and "Some type names are built-in", can you highlight me the difference which makes some assumption from my side which is wrong? For me "defined" in this context is a wide-meaning word; maybe you try to narrow it to C++ definition meaning like "somewhere in file with explicit statement or at least as an argument for compiler executable", but I mean where is it defined as essence stressing with "how it comes to my code".

Comment: (2)  For MSVC `size_t` is a known type and at the same time not a reserved word. So, your code compiles well with both MSVC (https://godbolt.org/z/h3zTYMxen) and CLang. With this I don't understand your message with "But since no header is included, size_t is not defined as a type, leaving the name available for the variable definition." and how it relates with (1).

Comment: @DamirTenishev: "Defined" has a very _very_ specific meaning in C++, see e.g. the One Definition Rule. Indeed, _definitions_ occur in source code. `float` is not a definition, and there is no place where it is defined.

Comment: But for `size_t`, the _usual_ definition is found in one of 7 header files. If none of those 7 headers are included in your Translation Unit, then you are free to provided your own definition of `size_t`, and that definition does not need to be a type definition. As in my example, where it is a variable instead.

Comment: Nd the fact the MSVC19 compiles my code means that `size_t` is NOT a "known" type, because it's not even a type in the example.

Comment: I understand that in your example `size_t` is not a type, I say that for MSVC considers it a type (no matter if you use it or not) and it doesn't conflict with your `size_t` variable because it is not a keyword. So, I still don't understand your aforementioned message. And what "Nd" stands for above?